# Compute the dimension of these subsets of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to compute the codimension of the subsets $S_1,S_2,S_3\subseteq\mathbb{R}^4$ given by
\begin{align}
S_1&=\{(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{R}^4:ad-bc\neq0,\},\\
S_2&=\{(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{R}^4:ad-bc=0,a+d\neq0\},\\
S_3&=\{(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{R}^4:ad-bc=0,a+d=0,a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2\neq0\},\\
\end{align}
but I don't know how to deal with the inequalities. How do you compute the dimension of something that is not a linear-subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: Note that $S_1\approx GL(2,\Bbb{R})$, that is open in $M(2,\Bbb{R})\approx\Bbb{R}^4$, then the codimension of $S_1$ is zero.

Comment: @Marc Correct...if the equality constraints are all independent, their number should equal the codimension (in a nonlinear sense). You are looking at submanifolds of $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: The other two sets correspond to non-zero matrices with either one or two eigenvalues being 0, but I don't know how to compute their dimensions

Comment: @Marc Well...dont look at the eigenvalues, consider the maximum number of independent numbers in the quadruple $(a,b,c,d)$

Comment: @Marc Note that if $(a,b,c,d)\in S_2$, then the vectors $v=(a,c)$ and $w=(b,d)$ are linearly dependents, then $w=kv,k\in\Bbb{R}$. How can this implies that $\dim(S_2)=2$? Think about it!

Comment: @Marc For $S_3$, the early case imples that $b=ka$ and $d=kc$, but we have $d=-a$, then $b=ka,\ c=-\frac{1}{k}a,\ d=-a$, then $\dim(S_3)=1.$